# Difference between codes - Rshiny reactive expressions

Tags: r, shiny

I'm learning Rshiny using the book Mastering Rshiny of Hadley Wickham.

In chapter 3, he gives the following example as the starting point to illustrate reactive expression (please note that "freqpoly" and "t_test" here are already defined functions by author, and they are not so important in this question)

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    x1 <- rnorm(input$n1, input$mean1, input$sd1)
    x2 <- rnorm(input$n2, input$mean2, input$sd2)
    
    freqpoly(x1, x2, binwidth = input$binwidth, xlim = input$range)
  }, res = 96)

  output$ttest <- renderText({
    x1 <- rnorm(input$n1, input$mean1, input$sd1)
    x2 <- rnorm(input$n2, input$mean2, input$sd2)
    
    t_test(x1, x2)
  })
}
```

He suggests that the following code with allows to execute the "freqpoly" and "t_test" function on the same datasets.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  x1 <- reactive(rnorm(input$n1, input$mean1, input$sd1))
  x2 <- reactive(rnorm(input$n2, input$mean2, input$sd2))

  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    freqpoly(x1(), x2(), binwidth = input$binwidth, xlim = input$range)
  }, res = 96)

  output$ttest <- renderText({
    t_test(x1(), x2())
  })
}
```

Then the author argues that we should not use imperative function in the place of reactive expressions because "any input will cause all outputs to be recomputed, and the t-test and the frequency polygon will be run on separate samples.". Here is the stated code:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  x1 <- function() rnorm(input$n1, input$mean1, input$sd1)
  x2 <- function() rnorm(input$n2, input$mean2, input$sd2)

  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    freqpoly(x1(), x2(), binwidth = input$binwidth, xlim = input$range)
  }, res = 96)

  output$ttest <- renderText({
    t_test(x1(), x2())
  })
}
```

My question is that: In the 3rd code, I see that the value of $x1$ and $x2$ are always calculated once when the inputs are updated. Then they are passed to renderPlot() and renderText(). So in fact, these 2 functions used the same simulated $x1$ and $x2$. Therefore, I don't think that they use different dataset, contradicts to what said by the author.

Can you help me to explain it ? Maybe i'm wrong somewhere ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```r
x1 <- reactive(rnorm(input$n1, input$mean1, input$sd1))
```

then any occurence of `x1()` in the server code is a *value*. When it is executed, this value is read. The body of `reactive` (`rnorm(......)`) is executed only when any of the reactive elements this reactive conductor contains (`input$n1/mean1/s1`) changes (this includes the initialization). So if you write `x1()` and the app is already initialized, this does not execute the expression `rnorm(......)`, this only read the reactive value `x1()`.

I like the name reactive *conductor* by the way. An ordinary function is not a "conductor": when you do

```r
x1 <- function() rnorm(input$n1, input$mean1, input$sd1))
```

then any occurence of `x1()` in the server code is a *call to the function `x1()`*. When the code is executed, this call is executed and its result is substituted to `x1()`.

Hence the third code is equivalent to the first one, even for the initialization.

For example, if you change `input$binwidth`, this will execute `x1()` and `x2()` in the `renderPlot` only, not in the `renderText`, in which nothing has changed, even after the execution of `x1()` in the `renderPlot`. This is like doing in the following in an ordinary code:

```r
a <- x1()
b <- x1()
```

When the second call to `x1()` is executed, to generate the value of `b`, that does not change the value of `a`. A "call" says: "hey, call me and I execute this expression and I return it to you". A "conductor" says: "hey all, take my value". The two calls above are isolated, whereas the schema for a reactive conductor would be:

```
a <--
     \_ x1()
     /
b <--
```

To convince yourself, you can do two histograms:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  x1 <- function() rnorm(input$n1, input$mean1, input$sd1)
  x2 <- function() rnorm(input$n2, input$mean2, input$sd2)

  output$hist1 <- renderPlot({
    freqpoly(x1(), x2(), binwidth = input$binwidth, xlim = input$range)
  }, res = 96)

  output$hist2 <- renderPlot({
    freqpoly(x1(), x2(), binwidth = input$binwidth, xlim = input$range)
  }, res = 96)
}
```

and you will observe they are different.